# Can circles drawn on a sphere (under specific conditions) intersect?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles, spheres

Gave the SAT exam recently and almost aced the Maths section. Almost because there was this one question I couldn't wrap my head around to solve. I don't remember the exact question, but it went something like this:

**If circles of radius 6 cm are drawn with their centre being a tangential point on the surface of a sphere of radius 10 cm, is it possible that any points of these circles will intersect?**

I tried to visualize it and the choice which seemed reasonable to me was 'No' which, now that I've received my results, I think was the wrong answer. The other choices were 'intersect at 1 point' and 'intersect at 2 points'. So please, could anyone mathematically explain what the answer to this question is?

Thanks!

Comment: Just asking: Have you tried sketching a sphere and two non-great circles on it? :)

Comment: @Andrew: I suspect that the circles are not on the sphere, but rather "tangential to it at their center," so to speak.

Comment: @Cameron: It occurred to me the circles might lie in tangent planes, but 1. After going back and forth on interpretation I picked one, since 2. The picture in either case is entirely similar. :)

Comment: @Andrew: Very true. I suppose that under my interpretation, the circles are effectively drawn on a sphere of radius $2\sqrt{34}$ with the same center as the smaller sphere.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the kicker: all such circles lie on a sphere. Depending on the interpretation of the problem, it is either the sphere of radius $10,$ or a sphere of radius $2\sqrt{34}$ (by Pythagorean Theorem) having the same center as the sphere of radius $10.$ In either case, these circles are not "great circles" (that is, their radius is less than the radius of the sphere), so they don't *have* to intersect (any two distinct great circles *must* intersect at exactly two points), but they *may* intersect. *If* two such circles intersect at all, they will intersect at either one point or two points (if two circles intersect at three or more points, then they are the same circle), and both are possible.

Comment: i remember '2' being an option in that question. so that's it. 2 is the right answer. tho, i didn't understand how you came up with that. could you please elaborate on it?

Comment: I can't right now, but I will later this afternoon.

Comment: Which part(s) of the answer are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: A visual proof.  I made it in Tinkercad.  The circles are radius 60mm and the sphere is radius 100 mm, as your question states.

[image]